# why does python allows me to access elements not specified in __all__ within a module?

Tags: python, import, module

I have the following directory structure:

```
.
├── main.py
└── myproj
    ├── __init__.py
    └── mymodule.py
```

This is **mymodule.py**:

```
hello = "hello"
byebye = "byebye"
class sayHello():
    def __init__(self):
        print("Hello World!")

class sayBye():
    def __init__(self):
        print("ByeBye World!")
```

I want only to expose the `sayHello` class when someone imports like: `from myproj import *`. My understanding is that this can be achieved by adding an `__all__` in the `__init__.py` file.

****init**.py**

```
__all__ = ["sayHello"]
```

but I can still access everything from the **mymodule.py** module
**main.py**

```
from myproj.mymodule import *

sayBye()
print(locals())
```

Output:

```
$ python main.py   
ByeBye World!
{'__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, '__package__': None, '__loader__': <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x10daf5210>, '__spec__': None, '__annotations__': {}, '__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>, '__file__': '/Users/simon/junk/main.py', '__cached__': None, 'hello': 'hello', 'byebye': 'byebye', 'sayHello': <class 'myproj.mymodule.sayHello'>, 'sayBye': <class 'myproj.mymodule.sayBye'>}
```

I can also access variables like `hello`, and `byebye`, which I was not expecting to. I was expecting some sort of error, since everywhere in the docs seems to imply that only the symbols specified in `__all__` will be exported.

Comment: I think `__all__ = ["sayHello"]` should be in `mymodule.py`

Comment: It seems that you have added `__all__` to `myproj`, but expecting it to affect `myproj.mymodule`

Comment: just to be clear, `__all__` only affects starred imports. It doesn't really affect what is visible in a module (*everything* is always visible). And furthermore, using starred imports is considered a bad practice in most cases.

Comment: Also note, when in `__init__.py`, then `__all__` is "taken to be the list of module names that should be imported when from package import * is encountered."